# Forgetting to return the result from a function: how to prevent this bug?

Tags: python, coding-style, python-3.x, static-analysis

I sometimes forget to `return result` from a function:

```
def f(*args):
  # do stuff
  result = # an expression
  # oops forgot to return result
```

Since `None` is a valid value in my application, this does not raise any exception or even any alarm in the caller. Of course, I'm trying to be careful. But I was wondering if there's some neat approach to warn me about any function that doesn't explicitly return a value.

Perhaps a regex I can run through my code to find such cases. Or some code checking tool (hopefully available under the Windows environment).

I was even thinking using a decorator like this:

```
def requires_return(func):
  def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    if result is None:
      print('Warning: {} may be missing a return statement'.format(func.__name__))
    return result
```

But this wouldn't work because:

1. Many false alarms: each time a function actually returns `None`. I can't stop using `None` in my application without creating really ugly code elsewhere.
2. In any case, adding a decorator to every function seems super-ugly.

Note that I do have functions where I intentionally don't have a `return` statement. I tend to maintain a certain naming convention, which allows me easily to distinguish them. (Specifically, every function that starts with `get_` must have a return statement.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pylint will sometimes catch this kind of error.  In particular if you assign to `result` but then never use it:

```
pylint zorg.py
************* Module zorg
W0612:  5:zorg: Unused variable 'result'
```

However, it does not catch the case where you build up `result` in pieces and then forget to return it (because then the variable is not "unused").

Depending on many other things, though, pylint, through its static type-analysis, may catch the failure to return a value.

Comment: I imagine you could try and search for cases of unused variable and no explicit return on the same function, which might give a pretty good estimation for finding this kind of thing.

Comment: Pylint is of course written in python, so you could add code for that.  It's ... not exactly trivial though. :-)  I keep wanting to add a few things myself; for instance, it currently fails to gripe if you have a "return expr" at some point in a function, and then fall off the bottom without an explicit "return None".

Comment: This is the closest we got to actually finding such situations. Much as I like the idea of good code practice, in some cases (e.g., old code), it's useful to find these cases.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest not getting into the habit of doing

```
def something():
    ...
    result = ...
    return result
```

Instead just do:

```
def something():
    ...
    return ...
```

Other than that, returning `None` by default is a useful feature 99% of the time.

Comment: I agree.. I didn't mean to say that returning None is not useful. I just want to check some existing code where I might have unintentionally omitted the return statement.

Comment: Python, as a duck-typed language, often leaves it up to the programmer to ensure logical strength rather than enforcing it. It's a strength or weakness of the language depending on how you look at it, and an inherent part of it. To be honest, I would argue that this is a pretty easy problem to spot when you run your code in general, so rather than doing anything fancy, I'd just run it and see.

Comment: -1 to the answer, +1 to the first part of your comment. -1 because while your suggestion might be a good practice, is not going to prevent the bug from happening. +1 to your comment because it is indeed up to the programmer to *ensure the logic* but with tests, not by "run it and see". Remember that there are no "easy problems", there are only easy to write tests.

Answer (score 4):

### Short Answer

In one word: [**unittest**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unittest.html).

This is not a problem that you should try to solve with your production code. A good set of tests will solve your problem.

### Unit Test 101

You should really learn what unit testing is, as a quick reference keep in mind that unit testing is about testing your API.

There's also something called [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (Test Driven Development) that is the practice to write the tests before the actual code. So the programmer write a test for a piece of code that doesn't exist, the test obviously fails, the programmer goes to the production code, write his function, run the tests, if the tests pass he move on.

It's a little hard at the beginning to come into the habit of writing tests, but it really pays off.

### Why Unit Test Here

I can't see how it could be possible to miss a return with the right set of tests.

> "Since `None` is a valid value in my application, this does not raise any exception or even any alarm in the caller."

What returning `None` does, is breaking your API. Unit testing is the exact cure for this.

> How to prevent this bug?

The way to *prevent* this bug is by using [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

If you write your tests first you are 99.9% sure of catching this bug before it even gets to be a bug.

**Note:** I know that this wasn't the answer you were looking for, but unit test is the right tools here. Not using the `result` variable or attaching a decorator to every function is not going to solve your problem.

Comment: +1 - That's what I'll do. Still, I think it would be nice to have this reported by a static code analyzer - just an extra way to catch it...

Answer (score 0):

It's better to prevent than to cure - meaning that you just should really learn the habit to return a value where necessary. Also you can use `return statement` directly instead of `result = statement; return result`.